# Interrupt and restart optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to use the Genetic Algorithm (GA) R-package for optimizing a land surface model. I need to be able to interrupt and restart the optimization at any given time because of node failures. In theory, this could be done by storing the GA output after each model run and reading the same output as an input for each subsequent model run. However, I don’t think this can be easily implemented using the GA package (version 3.2.3). Are there any other R-packages for model optimization that allow for stopping and restarting the optimization? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages that offer optimisation algorithms with checkpointing capabilities, allowing for stopping and restarting, include `caret`, `mlr`, and `h2o`.  Specifically:

`caret` has `trainControl` methods for saving models at intervals.

`h2o` is an R interface for the H2O scalable machine learning platform that has grid search and model saving options that can be stopped and resumed.

`mlr` is a machine learning package that offers benchmarking with resumption points.

These 3 packages all support Genetic Algorithm, as far as I know.

Each package has its own techniques for preserving the optimisation state, which can be restored in case of a disruption. In order to manage the restart manually, you would need to configure your optimisation process to save the state on a regular basis and load it as necessary.

Comment: Hi Robert - Thank you very much, I will look into those packages!